# If statement to check username and password entered in an iOS app

Tags: objective-c, ios

I need help for an if-else statement to check if the username and password matches. There'll be two text fields where the user inputs the username and password, a Submit button to login the user and also a label below it to display an error message if the username and password isn't valid. Once username and password is valid, the modal view will dismiss and take the user to the main page of the app. Below is the valid username and password:

Username: user1

Password: test123

My existing code below doesn't work.

```
if (usernameTextField.text == @"user1" && passwordTextField.text == @"test123")
{
    statusLabel.text = @"Success!";
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
else
{
    statusLabel.text = @"Incorrect. Please try again";
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks! :)

Comment: Usually people(I didn't downvote this) downvote this kind of questions to encourage the original poster to do some searches before asking such simple questions.

Comment: I actually searched but I didn't find the exact article I was looking for. I did find a related article but it seems too vague.

Comment: Your mistake is not understanding how the objective-c language works, which is often different to other languages. The `==` operator checks if two variables contain the same value, but the two variables you are checking are pointers to an object. Your code is checking if the *pointers* point to the *same* object. You've got two pointers to completely different objects, and you want to check if the contents of the objects is the same. Which is what the `-isEqualToString:` method is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think there's anything wrong in your code. However, try comparing the string values with the **isEqualToString** method and not the ==.

```
if([usernameTextField.text isEqualToString:@"user1"] && [passwordTextField.text isEqualToString:@"test123"])
    NSLog(@"Success");
```

Also, check that the textfields are connected in the nib.

Comment: I did some minor edits on my code and it did worked. Thanks again! :D